# What is the @package compiler directive for in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, package

I see `@package` a lot in Apple's header files, but for the life of me, I can't find an authoritative source that describes its meaning.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772600/what-does-the-package-directive-do-in-objective-c

Comment: I had trouble finding anything before I posted. Mainly because you can't search for a "@" symbol, in Google, here, or wherever.

Comment: Totally true, it is hard to search for. Besides, I like the answer to this question a lot better. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@package` is a scope declaration for a particular class member. There are four:

- **`@public`**: Accessible everywhere.
- **`@protected`**: Accessible within the class that defines it and inheriting classes.
- **`@private`**: Accessible within the class that defines it.
- **`@package`**: In 64-bit, like `@public`, but only within the same framework; in 32-bit, identical to `@public`.

See this [**developer doc**](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html) for more information.