# Objective-C basics: subclassing and member variable accessability

Tags: objective-c

Code below is pseudo code.
Imagine a class "Fruit" which has a factory method to create a fruit.

```
interface Fruit
{
}
+(Fruit*) createFruit:
{
  return [[Fruit alloc] init autorelease];
}
```

Now I want to subclass the Fruit to get an Apple:

```
interface Apple : Fruit
{
int iSeeds;
}
+(Apple*) createAppleWithColor: (int) iSeeds
{
Apple* oApple = [Apple createFruit:];
oApple.iSeeds = iSeeds;
return oApple;
}
```

Questions:

- How can I make "iSeeds" private so it cannot be changed from outside? If I add a "private" keyword it does not build anymore.
- Still I want to set iSeeds from inside my Apple's factory method.
- I want users allow to READ the content of iSeeds. So I suppose I should have a getter but I can't get it to work. I always get some error about "LValue assignment".
- The Fruit's createFruit is making use of autorelease. Does the Apple have to reatin/release anything?

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.

1. Your createFruit method is wrong.  It should be:

   ```
   + (Fruit *) createFruit {
     //autorelease, because the Create Rule only applies to CoreFoundation functions
     return [[[Fruit alloc] init] autorelease];
   }
   ```
2. Instance variables are `@protected` by default.  That means they can be directly accessed by the class and any subclasses.  You can make it `@protected`, `@private`, `@public`, and [`@package`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772600/what-does-the-package-directive-do-in-objective-c).  You do so like this:

   ```
   @interface Apple : Fruit {
     @private
     int iSeed
   }
   ...
   @end
   ```
3. If you want an instance variable to be readonly, then don't declare it as `@public`, but make a getter for it.  For example:

   ```
   - (int) iSeeds {
     return iSeeds;
   }
   ```
4. However, since the instance variable is readonly, you can't set it externally.  The way around this is to give the Apple a iSeed value during initialization:

   ```
   - (id) initWithSeeds:(int)aniSeedValue {
     if (self = [super init]) {
       iSeed = aniSeedValue;
     }
     return self;
   }
   ```

   Then make your `createAppleWithColor:(int)iSeeds` method like:

   ```
   + (Fruit *) createAppleWithColor:(int)iSeeds {
     return [[[Apple alloc] initWithSeeds:iSeeds] autorelease];
   }
   ```
5. Finally, you should read the [Naming Conventions guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) and the [Memory Management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: The convenience constructor would normally just be `fruit`.

Comment: @Chuck, agreed. I just added a link to go check out the Naming Conventions :)

Comment: I see. I still have a lot to learn.
Regarding naming conventions: I'll have to see if I can live with them. I'm coming from C# and currently I'm not willing to accept this obscure ObjectiveC style, but eventually I will adopt to it. :-)

What I don't get at all: "createAppleWithColor" is a method in the Apple class. Why can't it acces Apple's iSeed member? In C# it does not matter if a method is static, it is still a member of the class.

Comment: @Krumelur - you can do `apple->iSeeds = iSeeds` if you were to declare the instance variable as `@public`.  However, that reeks of bad design...

Answer (score 1):

One more thing.  If you have a factory method which applies to a class and its subclasses, you can (probably should) do this:

```
+(Fruit*) fruit
{
    [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

This means that if you invoke the method with a subclass, you'll get an object of the right type e.g.

```
Fruit* apple = [Apple fruit];
```

Of course, you'll need to provide an init method for Apple that provides a suitable default value for iSeeds and then invokes -initWithSeeds: