# iPhone SDK @package vs. @private vs. @public and struct

Tags: objective-c, iphone, package, private, public

Hey I have a really simple question that needs more of just an explanation than a debug, but I have seen in the interface definitions for many class objects the keywords "@package", "@private", "@public", and then even weirder "struct {...}". I have been able to make complete programs without using any of the aforementioned, so I was hoping someone could explain to me the significance of those keywords.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Wait, I understand now that the restictions of each declaration but why would you ever need to use them? And can you clarify what "struct {...}" means and how I use it? Thanks again :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concerning Package, your Question is answered here in detail: [What does the @package directive do in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772600/what-does-the-package-directive-do-in-objective-c)

struct is a C construct that lets you access multiple data types under a single name.

@private restricts access to variables to the use by just this class

@protected restricts access to variables to the use by just this class and inheriting classes ( default in Obj-C classes)

@package restricts access to variables to the use by the framework

@public lets everyone acces this variable

Edit:

```
struct person {         /* declares struct person */
int   age;
float weight;
char  name[25];
  } adam;

struct person joe;
joe.age = 23;        /* add values */
joe.weight = 147.8;
```

Concerning the restriction, its good OO Practice to restrict access to variables, known as encapsulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: "@public lets everyone acces this variable ( default in Obj-C classes)" `@public` is definitely not default

Comment: @user: You are right, I re-read the docu and its indeed @protected as default