# Synthesizing a property without instance variables

Tags: objective-c

I thought I understood @property and @synthesize, but I did some experimenting and I can't figure out why the below (what I thought was broken) code works.

As you can see, there's no instance variable that corresponds to the name property.  Does Objective-C somehow create an instance variable if it doesn't find an instance variable with the same name and type?

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddressCard : NSObject {

}

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
-(void) print;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "AddressCard.h"

@implementation AddressCard

@synthesize name;

-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"Name=%@", self.name);
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Test:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    AddressCard *ac = [[AddressCard alloc] init];
    ac.name = @"Brandon";
    [ac print];

    [ac release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The quick answer is: "yes". In Objective-C 2.0, synthesized properties will automatically create the corresponding ivars as required.

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) has some more details.

***Important:*** As pointed out by [Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427332/tommy) (**note:** this is from the legacy docs - please see [the latest information](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106)):

> In Objective-C 2.0 on either of the modern runtimes (ie, Intel 64bit and ARM) properties can be added to classes 'dynamically' (that is, at runtime but only before the creation of any instances — not particularly dynamic compared to the rest of the runtime). However, this can't be done on either of the two older runtimes (ie, Intel 32bit and PowerPC). It's therefore not really something you want to use on shipping software for the Mac or during development for iOS (since the simulator is a 32bit Intel application and can't create instance variables at runtime)

Comment: @e.James I did *not* know that. Learn something new every day.

Comment: This isn't quite true. In Objective-C 2.0 on either of the modern runtimes (ie, Intel 64bit and ARM) properties can be added to classes 'dynamically' (that is, at runtime but only before the creation of any instances — not particularly dynamic compared to the rest of the runtime). However, this can't be done on either of the two older runtimes (ie, Intel 32bit and PowerPC). It's therefore not really something you want to use on shipping software for the Mac or during development for iOS (since the simulator is a 32bit Intel application and can't create instance variables at runtime).

Comment: @Tommy: Thanks for the heads-up. I placed your comment right in the answer to make sure it gets noticed

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, since iOS 4.0.

Comment: @JustSid: It's been working for us since at least 3.x. But I guess it's a moot point now.

Comment: It definitely wasn't working for at least one person as of March this year — see comments on http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html . It definitely didn't work for me around about iOS 2.x, which was my most recent personal attempt...

Comment: it would/should warn you if it was a problem? an even the default window based application uses this 'feature' for window in appDelegate?

Comment: Link in answer no longer works. Apple rearranged their docs. Let's hope these last a while.

See "Runtime Difference" section at bottom of [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Also, [Runtime Version and Platforms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106).

Comment: Thanks, @je44ery. I updated the links to the ones you provided

Answer (score 2):

You can omit instance variable declaration only for 64-bit architecture

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that although the instance variable is automatically created, it's named the same as the property. By doing this, you may get bugs in your code later. So, besides preventing the case of not automatically generating on some architectures, you should always create the instance variable so that you don't get anything unexpected later on down the road.