# Is there a difference using self.variable = 'some value' to just variable = 'some value' for instance variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Let's say I have an instance variable NSDate *date; and I do (for example in viewDidLoad):

```
date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
```

or

```
self.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
```

Is there a difference between these two? And if there is which one is correct and possibly why :)

Thanx for answers 
Ladislav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. The first just assigns the value to the variable, while the other is assigning to a property and is thus the same as writing:

```
[self setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
```

For example, if you've defined your property as `@property(retain) NSDate *date;` the default implementation (through `@synthesize date`) will release the old value and retain the new value. You could also provide a custom `setDate:` implementation and do some actions when the date gets assigned. All of this doesn't happen if you just assign the value to the variable.

Comment: Does that mean, that if I do date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; date will be autoreleased, and when I try to access this variable at a later stage I might get EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Exactly (if you don't explicitly retain it later on). Or sometimes you don't get EXC_BAD_ACCESS but some other object was created at exactly the same location and you get funny results because of that.

Comment: That was what was going on...since sometimes I would get EXC_BAD_ACCESS and other times I wouldn't...Thanx

Answer (score 4):

Yes. self.date calls the setter of the property called date and if you have given something like retain in the property specification or if you have provided your own accessors they will be called.

It is always good idea to use self.date than date in most cases unless you are absolutely sure. Also note that present compiler allows you to just decale a property and synthesize without using your own variable declaration. It is preferred over explicit variable declaration. If you use that construct, you will get compiler errors whenever you use the variable directly without using the accessor, which is a nice to have advantage.

Comment: The *declare-property-without-backing-variable* feature [only works on x64 and iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511700/synthesizing-a-property-without-instance-variables), not on x86 (32 bit mode) and PPC, BTW.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust. That's good to know. From the linked question it seems like if we are building for pre iOS 4 we need to declare the backing variables.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring self.date = some value; you are actually doing the following things

if(date)[date release];
date = [somevalue retain];

Comment: only if the property is defined as (retain).

Comment: Also, if it were in the order you've written bad things will happen if you re-assign the same value as the release might cause the reference counter to drop to 0 and thus deallocate the object. The correct sequence is to first retain the new value, then release the old value, then assign the new value to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; here date is auto released object.

But if you use self.date and its property is retained,it is not a auto released object,we should explicitly release date

Comment: ...we should explicitly release date *in `dealloc`*.