# using @package. When and how to use it?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @package directive do in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772600/what-does-the-package-directive-do-in-objective-c)

I have only seen @package twice since starting iOS programming (and I've been doing this a while now).

What is @package used for? I believe it specifies where you can access variables from but I'm not sure of the exact rules?

Comment: Exact Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/772600/542425

Comment: ye I found this overly confusing. it makes reference to .net and I haven't used this in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s for cases when you write a portable library, the visibility level is then set to your library, but not for the other source code that will make use of it.

Comment: What a great answer. you might want to post on the above link. cheers

Comment: I noticed that right after I posted it, I guess they already have more detailed answers there…