# The title property of UIViewController subclass not accessible via iVar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, kvc

In the initialiser of a UIViewSubClass I'm setting the title property, using the iVar (avoiding the setter as recommended in initialisers):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _title = @"Pen";
    }
    return self;
}
```

No error is displayed when I type it, but when I compile or analize, I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._title", referenced from:
      -[PenViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in PenViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's going on? Is title not KVC compliant?

Comment: Have you tried simply `title`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the @package directive do in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772600/what-does-the-package-directive-do-in-objective-c)

Comment: Since you do not know the implementation of the title setter for UIViewController I would not recommend using the iVar and it is likely why you can't :)

Comment: @CarlVeazey I believe you are right. If you write this down as an answer, I'll accept it.