# Confused about UIViewController property in header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

On line 69 of `UIViewController.h` (in iOS 7), a public instance variable `id _dimmingView` is declared. However, after looking in the documentation and finding no answers, I have no idea what this is used for. Any ideas?

PS This could also be the case for a number of the instance variables declared in `UIViewController.h`, but I'm focusing on this one because I found it by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a public variable. It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772600/what-does-the-package-directive-do-in-objective-c) that `@package` means "internal to the framework", so in this case, UIKit. You cannot, and shouldn't, use `_dimmingView`. I don't believe this is publicly stated anywhere, but any symbol Apple uses that starts with _ is presumed to be private.

Comment: Also, it is exposed in the UIViewController header presumably because subclasses or other classes in the `@package` access it.